# Using Optional to avoid NPE

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I'm trying to avoid checking `(if ... != null)` or `try{...}catch(NullPointerException e) {...}`

Let's take an example to understand my issue :

I have a `class Park` containing `List<Car>`
I have a `class Car` containing a `Motor object`
I have a `class Motor` containing a `Name String` value

I want to return the first String motor name from my Park class :

I want to avoid :

```
if (park != null) {
    if (park.getCars() != null) {
        for (Car car : park.getCars() {
              if (car.getMotor() != null) {
                  return car.getMotor().getName();
```

I was thinking of something like this :

```
Optional.ofNullable(park).map(Park::getCars).ifPresent(cars -> {
    return cars.stream().map(Car::getMotor).map(Motor::getName).findFirst().orElse(null);
});
```

but it does not compile. Any ideas ??

Comment: Why do you suddenly use `ifPresent` instead of `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional.ifPresent()` has `void` as return type, so you can not return a result in the function. You can use `Optional.stream()` and `Stream.flatMap()` instead:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(park) // Optional<Park>
        .map(Park::getCars).stream() // Stream<List<Car>>
        .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Car>
        .map(Car::getMotor) // Stream<Motor>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Stream<Motor>
        .map(Motor::getName) // Stream<String>
        .findFirst() // Optional<String>
        .orElse(null);
```

Alternatively (if you can not use `Optional.stream()`) you can use `Optional.flatMap()` with the code you already have:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(park) // Optional<Park>
        .map(Park::getCars) // Optional<List<Car>>
        .flatMap(cars -> cars.stream() // Stream<Car>
                .map(Car::getMotor) // Stream<Motor>
                .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Stream<Motor>
                .map(Motor::getName) // Stream<String>
                .findFirst()) // Optional<String>
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems better. But I don't think I can use stream() on Optional<List<Car>> in the second line of your code...need to check that

Comment: @AntonBoarf Check again, I added another example using `Optional.flatMap()`.

Comment: thank tried it but none of them compiled. Checking why

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are limited to java 8, you can use this:

```
    public String findFirstMotorName(Park park) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(park)
            .map(Park::getCars)
            .map(
                cars -> cars.stream().map(Car::getMotor).map(Motor::getName).findFirst().orElse(null)
            )
            .orElse("No Motors Found");
    }
```

In later versions you can also turn an `Optional` to a `Stream`, which makes things a tad more fluent.